# Как сделать что бы при выборе option менялись все элементы с классом?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой селект:

```
<select id="select" class="header__select" form="form">
      <option class="header__option" value="22 526.92">USD</option>
      <option class="header__option" value="1477290.31">RUB</option>
      <option class="header__option" value="17342.97">GBP</option>
</select>
```

Есть три элемента:

```
<p id="price" class="ethereum__price--2 price">$22 526.92</p>
<p id="price" class="ethereum__price--2 price">$22 526.92</p>
<p id="price" class="ethereum__price--2 price">$22 526.92</p>
```

Мне нужно что бы при выборе оптион менялись все абзацы.

Так не работает (меняется только первый):

```
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('price');

document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", function(){
  price[length].innerHTML = "₽" +this.value;  
});
```

И еще как сделать что бы строка "₽" удалялась после выбора другого значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
  for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    prices[i].textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.prefix + " " + this.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="select" class="header__select" form="form">
  <option class="header__option" value="22 526.92" data-prefix="$">USD</option>
  <option class="header__option" value="1477290.31" data-prefix="₽">RUB</option>
  <option class="header__option" value="17342.97" data-prefix="£">GBP</option>
</select>

<p class="ethereum__price--2 price">$22 526.92</p>
<p class="ethereum__price--2 price">$22 526.92</p>
<p class="ethereum__price--2 price">$22 526.92</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо)) Буду учить дальше

Comment: @RavenTheX Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.